# Can I use 22536 port for SharePoint Apps development

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, windows-server, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running SharePoint on Windows Server 2012 on my local Virtual Machine. SharePoint site on that server is installed on port 22536. 
I am trying to setup environment for SharePoint App development on that VM but I am stuck at DNS Setting for Forward Lookup Zone and I am not able to complete its setup. I am very newbie to SharePoint Apps and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. 
[I am following steps from this link to setup environment for App development.](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Is it really necessary to run your sharepoint site from port 80 or 443 in order to develop or use sharepoint apps on sharepoint site or I am missing something in DNS configuration.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the correct information?

Comment: Have you tried it by extending the web application from port 22536 to port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in your given link at the end in **Beware of host headers** section that

> If you are using a host header for your web application apps won’t
>   just work for that web application. Because of how the redirect for
>   the app domain works IIS will try to resolve the app url by using the
>   default IIS web site, which of course doesn’t work. If you want to use
>   host headers for your web applications you have to create an extra web
>   application that is listening on port 80 (or 443 if you are using
>   https) and that doesn’t have a host header.
>
> This means that you have to create a web application like you normally
>   would. You have to make sure that you select port 80 (or 443 if you
>   are using https) and you should not fill in a host header. Note that
>   you have to stop the Default Web Site in IIS in order to be able to do
>   this. The web application will use the server name as its url. The web
>   application can be empty except for a root site collection.

**Solution**

You can **extend** your SharePoint Site installed on port 22536 to port 80 & use it for your `SharePoint Apps development`

Comment: Is above given information helps you?